# How to Convert date day time format to date only. example "07-13-2020 Mon 10:13:32 am" to "07-20-2020" in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day,

I am trying to fetch range of data in my database but i cant get any result when i try to query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM `doc_history` WHERE date BETWEEN '07-13-2020 Mon 10:13:32 am' AND '07-20-2020 Mon 01:24:28 pm'
```

but if i try only to search specific date. it normally show the data. but when it comes to RANGE SEARCH, it show nothing.

I am trying to convert this date format to a simplified date format "07-20-2020 Mon 01:24:28 pm" to "07-20-2020".

I tried others formula but still no result.

Comment: Operands in BETWEEN must be valid DATETIME literals - see [Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html). Fix this problem. PS. What is the datatype of `date` column?

Comment: varchar is as my date format is "07-13-2020 Mon 10:13:32 am"

Comment: Alter this column type and convert the data. As a palliative use generated column.

Answer (score 0):

You should valid [MySQL timestamp/datetime literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM doc_history
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m-%d-%Y %a %h:%i:%s %p')
    BETWEEN '2020-07-20 13:24:28' AND '2020-07-20 13:24:28';
```

But note that you are currently not really searching for a range, but rather a point in time.  So the above query I wrote is equivalent to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM doc_history
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m-%d-%Y %a %h:%i:%s %p') = '2020-07-20 13:24:28';
```

If you want a meaningful range, then the start and end values should be different points in time.

Comment: Good day sir, my format for my date is "j-M-Y h:i a". i also tried "date >= and date <=" . still no search

Comment: Is your `date` column _text_ or is it date/datetime/timestamp?

Comment: Sorry sir my i update my date range question. i use VARCHAR in data type sir

Comment: I have edited my answer.  You should stop storing your dates as text columns.  The query I gave you above is _not_ for long term use, it is only a temporary fix until you can replace `date` with a proper datetime column.